# CSS Flip Animation Resembling Flipboard

Tags: html, css

I have been following this tutorial: https://davidwalsh.name/css-flip and have run into some issues.

```css
.flip-container {
  perspective: 1000px;
}
/* flip the pane when hovered */

.flip-container:hover .flipper,
.flip-container.hover .flipper {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
.flip-container,
.front,
.back {
  width: 320px;
  height: 480px;
}
/* flip speed
goes here */

.flipper {
  transition: 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  position: relative;
}
/* hide back of pane during swap */

.front,
.back {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
/* front pane, placed above back */

.front {
  z-index: 2;
  /* for firefox 31 */
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
}
/* back, initially hidden pane */

.back {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
.vertical.flip-container {
  position: relative;
}
.vertical .back {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
.vertical.flip-container .flipper {
  transform-origin: 100% 213.5px;
  /* half of height */
}
.vertical.flip-container:hover .flipper {
  transform: rotateX(-180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
  <div class="flipper">
    <div class="front">
      <!-- front content -->
      <h1><center>This is the header</center></h1>
      <h4><center>Some useful info</center></h4>
      <p>
        <center>Bootstrap (currently v3.3.7) has a few easy ways to quickly get started, each one appealing to a different skill level and use case. Read through to see what suits your particular needs.Bootstrap (currently v3.3.7) has a few easy ways to quickly
          get started, each one appealing to a different skill level and use case. Read through to see what suits your particular needs.Bootstrap (currently v3.3.7) has a few easy ways to quickly get started, each one appealing to a different skill level
          and use case. Read through to see what suits your particular needs.Bootstrap (currently v3.3.7) has a few easy ways to quickly get started, each one appealing to a different skill level and use case. Read through to see what suits your particular
          needs.Bootstrap (currently v3.3.7) has a few easy ways to quickly get started, each one appealing to a different skill level and use case. Read through to see what suits your particular needs.</center>
      </p>

    </div>
    <div class="back">
      <!-- back content -->

      <h1><center>Title</center></h1>
      <h4><center>Sub</center></h4>
      <p>
        <center>Bootstrap (currently v3.3.7) has a few easy ways to quickly get started, each one appealing to a different skill level and use case. Read through to see what suits your particular needs.Bootstrap (currently v3.3.7) has a few easy ways to quickly
          get started, each one appealing to a different skill level and use case. Read through to see what suits your particular needs.Bootstrap (currently v3.3.7) has a few easy ways to quickly get started, each one appealing to a different skill level
          and use case. Read through to see what suits your particular needs.Bootstrap (currently v3.3.7) has a few easy ways to quickly get started, each one appealing to a different skill level and use case. Read through to see what suits your particular
          needs.Bootstrap (currently v3.3.7) has a few easy ways to quickly get started, each one appealing to a different skill level and use case. Read through to see what suits your particular needs.</center>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

***Everything works as it should except as I rotate the image, it flips up and out of the page. I would like to have the content stay in the same position it was before the flip, once it is flipped.***

[image]

And after it flips most of the content flips off the page:

[image]

Also, I would ultimately like to add a flipboard like flip animation expanding off of this example and wonder if it is possible. Any tutorials/ code examples would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add "`vertical`" `class` on "`flip-container`" `div`.